# Base entity in many to many relationships

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to implement BaseEntity class.
There i have fields: 
Id, CreatedDateTime, UpdatedDateTime, CreatedBy, UpdatedBy.

In my repository class i point this:

```
public interface IRepositoryBase<TEntity> where TEntity : BaseEntity
```

Is it will be correct to inherit BaseEntity also in every many-to-many entity?
Like this:

```
    public class OrderDish
{
    public int OrderId { get; set; }

    public Order Order { get; set; }

    public int DishId { get; set; }

    public Dish Dish { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your BaseEntity looks like this:

```
public interface BaseEntity
{
    DateTime? CreatedDate { get; set; }
    DateTime? UpdatedDate { get; set; }
    string CreatedBy { get; set; }
    string UpdatedBy { get; set; }
}
```

Create an Entity class from BaseEntity like:

```
public class Entity : BaseEntity
{
    protected Entity(){}
    public virtual string CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime? CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public virtual string UpdatedBy { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime? UpdatedDate { get; set; }
}
```

Inherit the other entitites from `Entity` like:

```
public class OrderDish : Entity
{
    public int OrderId { get; set; }
    public Order Order { get; set; }
    public int DishId { get; set; }
    public Dish Dish { get; set; }
}
```

You will be able to access the properties this way